# How to avoid popover size change when keyboard appear.?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, popover

I have a text field inside a popover. When I clicked the text field, the keyboard appear and the popover reduces its size. I want to avoid that size change. Any suggestions are appreciated.
Below is how I present the popover,

```
        let navVC: UINavigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: colorPickerVC)
        navVC.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

        let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController =  navVC.popoverPresentationController!
        popover = navVC.popoverPresentationController!
        popover.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        popover.sourceView = UIViewController.topMost()?.view
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = .any
```

[image]

Comment: an image will be more helpful. we don't know how you are applying constraints. show your code.

Comment: What do you mean by popover? A view controller having modal presentation style `popover` or are you simply talking about alert view or `UIAlertController`?

Comment: @Amila you need to pass sourceRect too for correct anchoring.  `popover.sourceRect = self.view.frame` try and let me know

Comment: @KetanParmar I have a viewController having modal presentation style popover

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com thanks for the suggestion. but it gives the same result

Comment: what are the constraint on your color selection view ?

Comment: color selection view is inside a Viewcontroller and the viewcontroller presented as a popover.

Comment: You're displaying this from some button click, right? If yes then your `sourceview` would be that button and you also need to set `sourcerect`(bounds of that button)!

Comment: @KetanParmar thanks for suggestion. I tried but it gives the same